# Python: use the arguments in enumerate as variable names for the nested loop

Tags: python, variables, arguments, nested-loops, enumerate

I would like to generate two data frames (and subsequently export to CSV) from two CSV files. I come up with the following (incomplete) code, which focuses on dealing with a.csv. I create an empty data frame (`df_a`) to store rows from itterows iteration (`df_b` is missing).

The problem is I do not know how to process b.csv without manually describing all avariables of empty dataframes in advance (i.e. `df_a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start', 'end'])` and `df_b = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start', 'end'])`).
I hope I can use the arguments of enumerate (ie. the content of `file`) as variables (ie. something like `df_file`) for the data frames (instead of `df_a` and `df_b`).

```
list_files = [a.csv, b.csv]

for i, file in enumerate(list_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)

    # Create empty data frame to store data for each iteration below
    df_a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start', 'end'])
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        var = df.loc[index, 'name']
        df_new = SomeFunction(var)
        # Append a new row to the empty data frame     
        dicts = {'start': df_new['column1'], 'end': df_new['column2']}
        df_dicts = pd.DataFrame([dicts])
        df_a = pd.concat([df_a, df_dicts], ignore_index=True)
    df_a_csv = df_a.to_csv('df_a.csv')
```

Ideally, it could look a bit like (note: `file` is used as a part of variable name `df_file`)

```
list_files = [a.csv, b.csv]

for i, file in enumerate(list_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)

    # Create empty data frame to store data for each iteration below
    df_file = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start', 'end'])
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        var = df.loc[index, 'name']
        df_new = SomeFunction(var)
        # Append a new row to the empty data frame     
        dicts = {'start': df_new['column1'], 'end': df_new['column2']}
        df_dicts = pd.DataFrame([dicts])
        df_file = pd.concat([df_file, df_dicts], ignore_index=True)
    df_file_csv = df_file.to_csv('df_' + file + '.csv')
```

Different approaches are also welcome. I just need to save the dataframe outcome for each input file. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`SomeFunction(var)` aside, can you get the result you seek without `pandas` for the most part?

```py
import csv
import pandas

## -----------
## mocked
## -----------
def SomeFunction(var):
    return None
## -----------

list_files = ["a.csv", "b.csv"]

for file_path in list_files:
    with open(file_path, "r") as file_in:
        results = []
        for row in csv.DictReader(file_in):
            df_new = SomeFunction(row['name'])
            start, end = df_new['column1'], df_new['column2']
            results.append({"start": start, "end": end})

    with open(f"df_{file_path}", "w") as file_out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, fieldnames=list(results[0].keys())):
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(results)
```

Note that you can also stream rows from the input to the output if you would rather not read them all into memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things we could comment, but I understand that you are concerned about not having to specify the loop for a and for b, given that you already are doing it in `list_files`.

If this is the issue, what about doing something like this?

```py
# CHANGED list only the stem of the base name, we will use them for many things
file_name_stems = ["a", "b"]

# CHANGED we save a dictionary for the dataframes
dataframes = {}

# CHANGED  did you really need the enumerate?
for file_stem in file_name_stems:
    filename = file_stem + ".csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)

    # Create empty data frame to store data for each iteration below
    # CHANGED let's use df_x as a generic name. Knowing your code, you will surely find better names
    df_x = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start', 'end'])
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        var = df.loc[index, 'name']
        df_new = SomeFunction(var)
        # Append a new row to the empty data frame     
        dicts = {'start': df_new['column1'], 'end': df_new['column2']}
        df_dicts = pd.DataFrame([dicts])

        df_x = pd.concat([df_a, df_dicts], ignore_index=True)
    # CHANGED and now, we print to the file
    csv_x = df_x.to_csv(f'df_{file_stem}.csv')
    # CHANGED and save it to a dictionary in case you need it
    dataframes[stem] = csv_x
```

So, instead of listing the exact filenames, you can list the stem of their name, and then compose de source filename and the output one.

Another option could be to list the source filenames and replace some part of the filename to generate the output filename:

```py
list_files = ["a.csv", "b.csv"]
for filename in list_files:
  # ...
  output_file_name = filename.replace(".csv", "_df.csv")
  # this produces "a_df.csv" and "b_df.csv"
```

Does any of this look to solve your problem? :)